# How to replace charactors after a matching pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby, replace

I have a variable (Multiline string ) content like below

```
host = hostname ,
ip = 192.168.0.0.1 ,
username = user1 ,
password = mypwd ,
tag = test
```

I want to mask\replace my password, before writing to a file .
please note: i may get content of variable like below also ( with single line )

```
host = hostname , ip = 192.168.0.1 , username = user1 , password = mypwd ,tag = test
```

In fact I want to replace 8 or 10 characters afer matching 'password'
How this can be active in Ruby ? (I use 2.5.1)
Also , variable content is not in Json format

Comment: Please provide a **valid** code sample. What is that "variable" supposed to be? A (multi-line) string? A file? A hash? 5 separate variables? (And not that it really matters, but your first mention of the `ip` is inconsistent/wrong.)

Comment: What do you mean by "get content of variable"? What is that supposed to be?

Comment: And what do you mean by "replace 8 or 10 characters"?? Do you actually mean something like "redact the password; replace all of its characters with `*`"? (Passwords may happen to be 8-10 characters, but I suspect that shouldn't be any limitation/assumption of your code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
str = "host = hostname , ip = 192.168.0.1 , username = user1 , password = mypwd , tag = test"
updated_str = str.gsub(/(?<=password\s=\s)[^,\s]*/, 'new_pass')

updated_str #=> "host = hostname , ip = 192.168.0.1 , username = user1 , password = new_pas , tag = test"
```

Comment: This is what I asked and it resolved my issue . Thank you very much Leo